# xpath query with backslashes return empty

Tags: excel, vba, xpath

I am trying to select a single MSXML2 node in excel using XPath predicates. I am able to select it just fine when I supply a string without backslashes. But as soon as I try with a file path string, the expression returns nothing.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Directory>
<Document>
    <Path/>
    <Status/>
    <Notes/>
</Document>
<Document>
    <Path>C:\Users\Ivelin\Desktop\Workspace\Requests\File.xlsm</Path>
    <Status>Started</Status>
    <Notes/></Document>
<Document>
    <Path>TEST</Path>
    <Status>Started</Status>
    <Notes/>
</Document>
</Directory>
```

This works:

```
Dim Stat As IXMLDOMNode
Dim strPath
strPath = "/Directory/Document[Path='TEST']/Status/text()"
MsgBox (strPath)
Set Stat = XDoc.SelectSingleNode(strPath) 
MsgBox (Stat.NodeValue)
```

This returns null:

```
Dim Stat As IXMLDOMNode
Dim strPath
strPath = "/Directory/Document[Path='C:\Users\Ivelin\Desktop\Workspace\Requests\File.xlsm']/Status/text()"
MsgBox (strPath)
Set Stat = XDoc.SelectSingleNode(strPath) 
MsgBox (Stat.NodeValue)
```

I tried different suggestions, double backslashes etc. but no luck. Since I am interested in file names/paths, I don't really have other option, but to use backslashes.

Any pointers on how to solve this are welcome.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you show the code for xdoc creation and population?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with your xpath. Perhaps the error lies elsewhere. I used the following loading your xml from file; no problem.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim xmlDoc As Object, item As Object
    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument") 'New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    With xmlDoc
        .validateOnParse = True
        .setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
        .async = False
        If Not .Load("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test.xml") Then
            Err.Raise .parseError.ErrorCode, , .parseError.reason
        End If
    End With
    Dim path As String
    path = "/Directory/Document[Path='C:\Users\Ivelin\Desktop\Workspace\Requests\File.xlsm']/Status/text()"
    Set item = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(path)
    Debug.Print item.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, this works for me indeed. I had Microsoft XML 3 in references, after changing to Microsoft XML 6 it works. Thanks for the help!